# How to parse/map JavaFX CSS file to retrieve its properties and values?

Tags: java, css, parsing, javafx

My application allows users to use custom CSS themes to style the interface.  I have several pre-built "themes" available to choose from that are very simple, with only 3 properties.

**Sample CSS:**

```
.root{
    -fx-background: #325c81;
    -fx-default-button: #77a3ca;
    -fx-base: #a7c4dd;
}
```

The application has 3 `ColorPicker` controls that need to allow users to select a color for each of those properties and save back to the CSS file.

I have no problem with actually writing the CSS file, but I cannot find a way to parse the `.css` file in order to set the values of the `ColorPicker` controls with the values from the `.css` file.

**Basic Program Flow**

1) User selects a premade theme from `ComboBox`:

```
cboPresetTheme.valueProperty().addListener((observable, priorTheme, newTheme) -> {
                Utility.applyTheme(cboPresetTheme.getScene(), newTheme);
            });
```

2) The associated `.css` file is loaded and applied to the current `Scene`:

```
public static void applyTheme(Scene scene, Theme theme) {
    scene.getStylesheets().clear();

    File css = new File("themes/" + theme.getFileName());
    File fontFile = new File("themes/Font.css");

    scene.getStylesheets().addAll(
            css.toURI().toString(),
            fontFile.toURI().toString());
}
```

3) The 3 `ColorPicker` controls are updated with the values from the applied `StyleSheet`:

```
cpBackground.setValue(Color.valueOf(cssFileBackground));
cpBase.setValue(Color.valueOf(cssFileBase));
cpDefaultButton.setValue(Color.valueOf(cssFileDefaultButton));
```

While I have no problem with steps 1 & 2, I do not know how to process step 3.

I have looked at other CSS Parser libraries (thank you, Google) but they seem more geared toward stand CSS and don't support FX properties. The StackExchange question [edit or parse FX-CSS file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776022/javafx-edit-or-parse-fx-css-file-programmatically) appears to be asking the same question but it was never successfully answered.

One answer suggests using [CSS Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/) to accomplish this, but as there is little to know documentation (and what is there is beyond my current comprehension level), I don't know where to begin.

I understand there may not be a standard API currently available to accomplish this, but I was hoping there may be a simple library or solution out there that I have been unable to find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways you can tackle the conversion of a CSS declaration into a Color.

**Style an auxiliar node**

This is quite simple, but effective: The idea is that you could just style the background color of a node with the same css, and then set the colorPicker value with that color.

The only thing you need to take into account in this case is that the node is styled *only* when is added to a scene.

So you have to add the node to the scene. Adding a node with 0x0 size won't cause any issue, but maybe you don't want it to be there, so you can use an auxiliar scene.

```
public class CSSParsingApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ColorPicker cpBackground = new ColorPicker(retrieveColor("value1"));
        ColorPicker cpBase = new ColorPicker(retrieveColor("value2"));
        ColorPicker cpDefaultButton = new ColorPicker(retrieveColor("value3"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, cpBackground, cpDefaultButton, cpBase);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Color retrieveColor(String value) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getStyleClass().add(value);

        Scene sceneAux = new Scene(pane);
        sceneAux.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        pane.applyCss();
        return (Color) pane.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getFill();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

where `style.css` is:

```
.root {
    -fx-background: #325c81;
    -fx-default-button: #77a3ca;
    -fx-base: #a7c4dd;
}

.value1 {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
}
.value2 {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-default-button;
}
.value3 {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-base;
}
```

**Use StylableProperties**

A similar, more elegant solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625212/convert-color-from-css-to-javafx-color-object). It uses `StylableProperties` to create a node, that you can style with a custom `-named-color` property, and then adds this `helper` node to the main scene.

Basically it is the same idea as the one above, maybe more clean, as you don't need to modify your css file.

Using `CssToColorHelper`, your code will be like this:

```
public class CSSParsingApp extends Application {

    private CssToColorHelper helper = new CssToColorHelper();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ColorPicker cpBackground = new ColorPicker();
        ColorPicker cpBase = new ColorPicker();
        ColorPicker cpDefaultButton = new ColorPicker();  

        VBox root = new VBox(10, cpBackground, cpDefaultButton, cpBase, helper);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        cpBackground.setValue(getNamedColor("-fx-background"));
        cpDefaultButton.setValue(getNamedColor("-fx-default-button"));
        cpBase.setValue(getNamedColor("-fx-base"));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Color getNamedColor(String name) {
        helper.setStyle("-named-color: " + name + ";");
        helper.applyCss();

        return helper.getNamedColor();      
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

where `style.css` is your css file:

```
.root {
    -fx-background: #325c81;
    -fx-default-button: #77a3ca;
    -fx-base: #a7c4dd;
}
```

**Use JavaFX CssParser**

If you are looking for a CSS parser, why don't you just use the one included in JavaFX, the one you actually use to apply styling to your app?

It is under `javafx.css.CssParser`, and it has been a part of the public API since [JavaFX 9](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/CssParser.html).

With it you can parse the CSS file and retrieve any parsed value easily.

```
 public class CSSParsingApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ColorPicker cpBackground = new ColorPicker();
        ColorPicker cpBase = new ColorPicker();
        ColorPicker cpDefaultButton = new ColorPicker();  

        VBox root = new VBox(10, cpBackground, cpDefaultButton, cpBase);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        cpBackground.setValue(parseColor("-fx-background"));
        cpDefaultButton.setValue(parseColor("-fx-default-button"));
        cpBase.setValue(parseColor("-fx-base"));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Color parseColor(String property) {
        CssParser parser = new CssParser();
        try {
            Stylesheet css = parser.parse(getClass().getResource("style.css").toURI().toURL());
            final Rule rootRule = css.getRules().get(0); // .root
            return (Color) rootRule.getDeclarations().stream()
                .filter(d -> d.getProperty().equals(property))
                .findFirst()
                .map(d -> ColorConverter.getInstance().convert(d.getParsedValue(), null))
                .get();
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) { }
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

where `style.css` is your css file:

```
.root {
    -fx-background: #325c81;
    -fx-default-button: #77a3ca;
    -fx-base: #a7c4dd;
}
```

Comment: Using the built-in CSSParser looks promising, thank you!  However, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on 
`Stylesheet css = parser.parse(Utility.class.getResource(cssFile).toURI().toURL());' My `cssFile` is being passed as a String to the `.css` file in question.

Comment: Make sure you have a valid `cssFile` under the same path as the `Utility` class. Also place an `ex.printStackTrace()` in the catch, so you can find out the reason of that exception.

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with `Utility.class` being null (the String checks out fine). I am putting the parser in a `Static` method so I can't use `getClass()`.

Comment: The `cssFile` string contains the full relative path to the file; will that not work? And the `e.printStackTrace()` only leads me to that line. Is there a way to find out which part of the line is causing the exception?

Comment: I suggest you use just the name of the css file, and place it under the same package path as `Utility` class. Or use an absolute path, and use `"/" + cssFile` as path to get the resource.

Comment: I can't actually place the `.css` into the package with `Utility` as the StyleSheets are distributed as external files.

Comment: Why don't you use the same approach you already have? Use your `css` file and then call `parser.parse(css.toURI().toURL())`.

Comment: I actually just caught that too :) Will give it a shot, thank you!

Comment: That did it. Thanks again, Jose!